# Understanding the printf function in assembly, nasm, x86. I don't know why this code isn't printing anything out

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

```
BITS 64;

          global    main
          extern    printf

          section   .text
main:                                       ; This is called by the C library startup code
          push      rbx                     ; required to make printf 16-byte aligned.
                                            ; For now we only do this once!
          
          push      qword 300
          call      sum 

          mov       rdi, dfmt               ; set 1st parameter (format)
          mov       rsi, rax                  ; set 2nd parameter (low byte)
          xor       rax, rax                ; because printf is varargs we must clear rax
          call      printf                  ; printf(format, current_number)

          pop       rbx                     ; must restore rbx for Linux
          ret                               ; Return from main back into C library wrapper

sum:
      push      rbp                     ; retrieve parameter
          push      rbx                     ; save previous 
          mov       rbp, rsp
          add       rsp, 24                 ; create room for integer
          mov       rbx, [rbp]              ; rbx = param
            
          cmp       rbx, 0                  ; if (n <= 0)
          je        base                 
          
          dec       rbx                     ; decrement rbx to place in stack
          push      rbx                     ; put (rbx - 1) in stack
          inc       rbx
          call      sum                     ; calculate sum(n - 1)
          add       rax, rbx     
          pop       rbx 
          
          jmp end
          base:
          mov       rax, 1
          
          end:
          pop       rbx
          pop       rbp
          ret
           
dfmt:
          db  "%ld", 10, 0
```

Comment: Note that the `push qword 300` again misaligns the stack and you don't even remove that argument from the stack. Might or might not be the cause of your printing problem but it's sure to make your program crash. Also `add rsp, 24 ` is not allocating space, it's freeing space. You want a `sub`. Then again, you don't need any stack space so what's the point? Also `mov  rbx, [rbp]` is not the parameter.

Comment: Also `sum` is a total mess, starting with *`add rsp,24`* (not sub), so its later pushes overwrite main's stack frame.  And its own, recursively, since it calls itself.  And `[rbp]` isn't where its stack arg is.  (Normally you'd pass args in a register anyway).  I assume this segfaults, but you haven't said exactly what happens (a necessary part of a [mcve]).  Single-step it with a debugger, and find yourself an example of a working recursive factorial or something else trivial, because there's a bunch of misunderstandings to clear up.  There should be some on Stack Overflow if you google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this bit by bit.

In the `main` function you have `push qword 300`.  I assume this is meant to pass an argument to `sum`?  If so... that's not what you are doing.  I would recommend instead following the AMD64 calling convention and using `mov rdi, 300` and then `call sum`, which would expect to find its first argument in `rdi`.

In any case, in `sum` the first thing you do is `push rbp`, which is pretty standard.  Then you `push rbx`.  That's a callee-saved register, so fine.  Then `mov rbp, rsp` which is, again, pretty standard.

Now you *free* some stack with `add rsp,24`, which I don't understand.  The stack grows toward lower addresses, so to reserve some stack you would *subtract* from `rsp`.  But maybe that's not what you are doing?

Now it really gets confusing to me.  You do `mov rbx, [rbp]`, but since `rbp` wasn't modified by the `main` function, it isn't going to be pointing anywhere we want it to be.  I can only assume this is some attempt to get at an argument on the stack?

Honestly, at this point I am stumped.

It is usual to start your function with the following boilerplate.

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
```

The reason is to protect the stack.  Now all references can be done with respect to `rbp`, which *never changes* in your code (it always points to *your* stack frame).  It is a callee-saved register, so we have to save it anyway, and do so on the stack just before setting it.

It is usual to end your function with the following boilerplate.

```
mov rsp, rbp
pop rbp
ret
```

This restores the stack pointer and `rbp` to what they were on entry, as required by the AMD64 calling convention.  There is a synonym for this: `leave`.  The following code is equivalent.

```
leave
ret
```

Now, when you use `printf` (or any function that might make use of the `xmm` registers) you have to also make sure the stack is aligned on a 16-byte boundary before you call.  You can assume the stack is aligned on entry to `main`.  The `push rbp` will mess it up (off by 8), but when you execute `call printf` you will push 8 more bytes (the return address) and presto!  The stack is aligned.

My last recommendation is to use the AMD64 calling convention and not use the stack.  Put the argument in `rdi`, and obtain the return value in `rax`.

I can't offer more help without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Agreed, from the comment on `mov  rbx, [rbp]  ;rbx = param`, they're trying to load the stack arg they pushed in main, but apparently they haven't understood or thought through what any of the instructions are doing.  They're reloading the saved-RBX value (because they pushed RBX before `mov rbp, rsp` set up RBP as a frame pointer that's not pointing to the usual spot in the stack frame for a legacy frame pointer).  I also wonder if the `add rsp, 24` was mixed up with what was supposed to be `[rbp + 24]`. But so mixed up that it should just get tossed and replaced with a fresh understanding :/